# How to solve the error: Cannot update a component (`Component`) while rendering a different component (`otherComponent`)

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm building a dynamic Alert UI with tailwindcss. I want to make this alert so that it can be used anywhere when making all requests. I also combine the Alert with the value in the global state. Overall it works well, however there are the following caveats: 
[image]

this the global state of alert used redux toolki:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const uiSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'UI',
    initialState: {
        offcanvasVisible: false,
        alert: {
            isShow: false,
            variant: '',
            message: '',
        },
    },
    reducers: {
        offcanvasToggle: (state) => {
            state.offcanvasVisible = !state.offcanvasVisible;
        },
        showAlert: (state, action) => {
            state.alert.isShow = true;
            state.alert.message = action.payload.message;
            state.alert.variant = action.payload.variant;
        },
        closeAlert: (state) => {
            state.alert.isShow = false;
            state.alert.message = '';
            state.alert.variant = '';
        },
    },
});

export const { offcanvasToggle, showAlert, closeAlert } = uiSlice.actions;
export default uiSlice.reducer;
```

the following code in the Alert component:

```
import { BiNoEntry } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { IoCloseSharp } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { BsCheckCircleFill, BsFillInfoCircleFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { closeAlert } from '../../store/ui-slice';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Alert = () => {
    const [showState, setShowState] = useState(false);
    const [variantState, setVariantState] = useState('');
    const [messageState, setMessageState] = useState('');
    const [classes, setClasses] = useState('');

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { variant, message, isShow } = useSelector((state) => state.ui.alert);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isShow) return;

        setShowState(isShow);
        setVariantState(variant);
        setMessageState(message);

        if (variant === 'info') {
            setClasses('bg-blue-400 border-blue-500');
        }

        if (variant === 'success') {
            setClasses('bg-green-400 border-green-500');
        }

        if (variant === 'failed') {
            setClasses('bg-red-400 border-red-500');
        }
    }, [isShow, variant, message]);

    return (
        <div
            className={`${
                !showState && 'hidden'
            } container-custom w-full py-4 text-white flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-between ${classes}`}
        >
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <span>
                    {variantState === 'info' ? (
                        <BsFillInfoCircleFill size="24" />
                    ) : variantState === 'success' ? (
                        <BsCheckCircleFill size="24" />
                    ) : variantState === 'failed' ? (
                        <BiNoEntry size="24" />
                    ) : (
                        ''
                    )}
                </span>
                {messageState}
            </div>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(closeAlert());
                }}
                className="text-white"
            >
                <IoCloseSharp color="white" size="24" />
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Alert;
```

Code in the Contact Component:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title */
import LandingLayout from '../../components/Layout/LandingLayout';
import Breadcrumb from '../../components/UI/Breadcrumb';
import Input from '../../components/Form/Input';
import TextArea from '../../components/Form/TextArea';
import { AiOutlineWhatsApp } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { BsInstagram } from 'react-icons/bs';
import {
    MdOutlineAddLocationAlt,
    MdOutlineEmail,
    MdPhone,
} from 'react-icons/md';
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
    sendingEmail,
    turnOffLoadingSendEmail,
    turnOnLoadingSendEmail,
} from '../../store/landing-slice';
import Spin from '../../components/UI/Spin';
import { showAlert } from '../../store/ui-slice';

const Kontak = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { loading, success, error } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.landing.sendEmail
    );

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors, isValid },
        reset,
    } = useForm({
        mode: 'all',
    });

    if (success !== null) {
        dispatch(showAlert({ variant: 'success', message: success.message }));
    }

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        if (!isValid) return;

        dispatch(turnOnLoadingSendEmail());

        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(sendingEmail(data));
            dispatch(turnOffLoadingSendEmail());
            reset();
        }, 1000);
    };

    return (
        <LandingLayout>
            <Breadcrumb title="Kontak Kami" />
            <section className="container-custom py-10 w-full h-[450px] overflow-hidden">
                <iframe
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3960.687915874803!2d107.64700641530236!3d-6.927857094994467!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2e68e80a699f1971%3A0xca4c51951a56650c!2sPanti%20Asuhan%20Al-Hidayah!5e0!3m2!1sid!2sid!4v1666696368586!5m2!1sid!2sid"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    style={{ border: 0 }}
                    allowFullScreen=""
                    loading="lazy"
                    referrerPolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
                />
            </section>
            <section className="container-custom py-4 w-full flex flex-col gap-10 md:flex-row-reverse">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full">
                    <h2 className="text-gray-700 text-lg mb-3">
                        Hubungi kami melalui form dibawah ini.
                    </h2>
                    <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:gap-3">
                        <Input
                            options={{
                                ...register('name', {
                                    required: 'Nama Lengkap tidak boleh kosong',
                                }),
                            }}
                            id="name"
                            label="Nama Lengkap"
                            requireIcon="true"
                            hasError={!!errors?.name}
                            errorMessage={errors?.name?.message}
                        />
                        <Input
                            options={{
                                ...register('email', {
                                    required: 'E-Mail tidak boleh kosong',
                                    pattern: {
                                        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                                        message: 'Invalid email address',
                                    },
                                }),
                            }}
                            id="email"
                            label="E-Mail"
                            requireIcon="true"
                            hasError={!!errors?.email}
                            errorMessage={errors?.email?.message}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <Input
                        options={{
                            ...register('subject', { required: 'Subjek tidak boleh kosong' }),
                        }}
                        id="subject"
                        label="Subjek"
                        requireIcon="true"
                        hasError={!!errors?.subject}
                        errorMessage={errors?.subject?.message}
                    />
                    <TextArea
                        id="keterangan"
                        label="Keterangan"
                        options={{
                            ...register('keterangan'),
                            rows: '4',
                        }}
                    ></TextArea>
                    <Button
                        className="flex gap-2"
                        options={{
                            type: 'submit',
                            disabled: !isValid,
                        }}
                    >
                        {loading && <Spin />}
                        Kirim
                    </Button>
                </form>
                <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-2 md:gap-4">
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                        <span className="self-start rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 p-3">
                            <MdOutlineAddLocationAlt size={32} />
                        </span>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                            <h3 className="pt-5 font-semibold text-[17px]">Alamat</h3>
                            Jl. Trs. St. Kiaracondong, RT.02/RW.08, Kebun Jayanti, Kec.
                            Kiaracondong, Kota Bandung, Jawa Barat 40281
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                        <span className="self-start rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 p-3">
                            <MdPhone size={32} />
                        </span>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                            <h3 className="pt-5 font-semibold text-[17px]">Telepon</h3>
                            022 7333116
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                        <span className="self-start rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 p-3">
                            <AiOutlineWhatsApp size={32} />
                        </span>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                            <h3 className="pt-5 font-semibold text-[17px]">Whatsapp</h3>
                            0882 43556 7721
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                        <span className="self-start rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 p-3">
                            <BsInstagram size={32} />
                        </span>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                            <h3 className="pt-5 font-semibold text-[17px]">Instagram</h3>
                            yayasan_alhidayah
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                        <span className="self-start rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 p-3">
                            <MdOutlineEmail size={32} />
                        </span>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                            <h3 className="pt-5 font-semibold text-[17px]">E-Mail</h3>
                            alhidayahkircon@gmail.com
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </LandingLayout>
    );
};

export default Kontak;
```

I put the Alert on the Navbar:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../UI/Logo';
import { FiMenu, FiPhone } from 'react-icons/fi';
import Button from '../UI/Button';
import Dropdown from '../UI/Dropdown';
import { BiDonateHeart } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { AiOutlineHistory } from 'react-icons/ai';
import Alert from '../UI/Alert';

const Navbar = (props) => {
    return (
        <header className="sticky top-0 z-10 bg-white border-b-2 border-slate-200">
            <Alert />
            <div className="container-custom flex justify-between items-center">
                <div className="w-36 pl-2 md:pl-0">
                    <Link to="/">
                        <Logo />
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <ul className="hidden lg:flex font-medium">
                    <li className="mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4 rounded-md">
                        <Link to={'/'}>Beranda</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4 rounded-md">
                        <Link to={'/kegiatan'}>Kegiatan</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4 rounded-md">
                        <Dropdown label="Donasi">
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link className="flex items-center" to="/donasi">
                                    <span className="mr-3">
                                        <BiDonateHeart />
                                    </span>
                                    Formulir Donasi
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link className="flex items-center" to="/cek-donasi">
                                    <span className="mr-3">
                                        <AiOutlineHistory />
                                    </span>
                                    <p>Cek Donasi</p>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        </Dropdown>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4 rounded-md">
                        <Dropdown label="Tentang Kami">
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link to="/profil-lembaga">Profil Lembaga</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link to="/visi-misi">Visi & Misi</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link to="/galeri">
                                    <p>Galeri</p>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <Link to="/kontak">Hubungi Kami</Link>
                            </li>
                        </Dropdown>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="hidden lg:grid grid-cols-2 gap-1">
                    <a
                        className="flex items-center mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4 rounded-md"
                        href="tel:+0222334645"
                    >
                        <FiPhone size={'24'} />
                        <span className="ml-2">022 2334645</span>
                    </a>
                    <Button
                        className="flex justify-center items-center"
                        options={{
                            type: 'link',
                            href: '/donasi',
                        }}
                    >
                        Donasi
                        <span className="ml-1">
                            <BiDonateHeart />
                        </span>
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="lg:hidden" onClick={props.offcanvasToggle}>
                    <FiMenu size={32} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

and here's what the UI should look like:
[image]

First of all, I thank you for being petrified

I hope I can use the best way to implement Alert without Warning like this.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because your updates to state are cascading. Your first `set` is causing the DOM to update. The update isn't yet complete, so your second (or third) `set` is also trying to update the DOM, and causing conflict.

I have found that when I have situations where I'm updating multiple state variables simultaneously it is better to use `useReducer` instead of `useState`. You can then setup a `dispatch` method that updates your multiple bits of state simultaneously, and even provide multiple methods that do different updates conditionally. This way `state` updates are concurrent, and avoid the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one important thing in advance. Since the beginning I've been using redux for global multiple state. I've updated the code above